# css and html coding for decorating menu bar and positioning elements

Tags: html, css

I want to make my homepage to look like the example website "kate spade"

"http://www.verticalresponse.com/blog/10-examples-of-highly-effective-welcome-emails/" This is the link for the website. I want to make my homepage like the 4th example (which is the "kate spade" website)

I am not just copying a website because I will not publish my website. This is just for practice.

Specifically, I want to make my menu bar look like the menu bar in the image and I want to put my navigation bar "contact me" inside my image like the website. Can you please help me fixing my homepage?

The following is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>

Jiwon's Website

</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>


<div id= "menu">
<ul>
<li> <a href="home.html"> Home </a> </li>
<li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="About Me.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact </a></li>
</ul>
</div>



<img src="image/thankletter.png" width="900" height="600" alt="thank you letter">





<h4> <a href="contact.html"> CONTACT ME ▶ </a> </h4>








</body>

</html>
```

The following is my css code

```
html { background: #ffffff ;}html { background: white url(image/follower.png) repeat;}

Body {font-family: FZYaoTi, arial, sans serif; font-size: 100% ; text-align: left ; width: 800px;  height: 100% ; margin: auto ; padding: 25px 50px  ; }


p {font-family: "Harlow Solid Italic", "arial", font-size: 16pt   ; }

a {text-decoration: none; color: blue   ; }


h2 {margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px ; border-style:solid; border-width: 50px ; border-color: #f4d03f  ;  padding: 50px; background: white; }



#menu {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    background: #4d5656; /*This changes the color of your menu bar*/
    width:900px; /*This will depend on the width of your website content; it should be the “width” property in your body{} selector PLUS the “margin” property in your body{} selector*/
    font-family: "myriad pro", "arial", "sans serif"; /*This should be the SAME as the font selection from the body{} selector...you can copy and paste, even*/
font-size: 14pt; /*This changes the size of the font for your menu…or you can leave it normal-sized*/
color: #fff; /*This changes the color of the font for your menu*/
    position:relative; 
    left: -50px; /*What are your left-right “padding” properties in your body{} selector? This should be the sum of both. Example: If padding: 25px 0px; then this should be -50 px; if padding: 30px 0px; then this should be -60 px; */
    text-align:left;
}













/*Individual menu items*/


#menu ul {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;   
   list-style:none;
   float:right;
   position:relative;
   right:50%;
}



#menu ul li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
}




#menu ul li a {
   display: block;
   padding: 0px 40px; /*This says how much space is between each menu item, left-right. How far apart do you want your menu items to be?*/
   line-height:60px; /*How tall do you want your menu to be?*/
   background: #4d5656; /*This should be the SAME as the background color up in the first #menu section*/
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#fff; /*This changes the color of the text for menu items. We need this because each one is also a link, and will otherwise show up as bright blue*/
}


#menu ul li a:hover {
   background:#fff; /*This should be the SAME as the default background color behind your text*/
   color: #4d5656; /*This should be the SAME as the background color up in the first #menu section*/
  }
```

Comment: A code snippet would had been better, so that we may have a working sample

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please read this article about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to let use help you better.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get what you want, instead of using the img tag use a div with a background and place the link inside the link.

No need to use h4

**HTML**

```
<div id="contact">
    <a href="contact.html" title="go to contact">Contact></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contact {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(../image/thankletter.png) no-repeat;
}
#contact a {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I hope I have helped

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But, I already have a flower background image. I want to keep my background and I just want to put my "contact me" nav bar inside my "thank you letter" image.